# Java parse through string and extract data from it using keyword search

Tags: java, json, parsing

I need to loop through a bunch of JSON snippets in Java and extract two pieces of data from each. For example:

> "id":8041841931,"title":"Black","option1":"Black","option2":null,"option3":null,"price":"83.79","grams":4706,"compare_at_price":null,"sku":"","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"position":3,"product_id":2759169283,"created_at":"2015-09-23T20:51:28-04:00","updated_at":"2015-09-23T20:51:28-04:00","available":true,"featured_image":null},

I need keep track of the "price" and "grams" of each of these snippets then eventually sort them in ascending order by grams. These snippets are all in an array of **String[]**. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Have a look at [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) to help you parse JSON in Java.